# @JsonProperty is not working as expected for Spring Request

Tags: java, spring, jackson, swagger-2.0

After applying `@JsonProperty` on field I am getting both field name and the property name in spring request.

```
public class RequestDto {

    @JsonProperty("reference_id")
    private String referenceId;

    @JsonProperty("reference_type")
    private String referenceType;

    @JsonProperty("patient")
    private Patient patient;
}
```

&

```
public class Patient {

    @JsonProperty("birth_date")
    private String birthDate;

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

The conversion in spring swagger request is as below

```
{
  "requestDto" : {
    "referenceId" : "string",
    "referenceType" : "string",
    "patient": {
      "birthDate": "string",
      "birth_date": "string",
      "firstName": "string",
      "first_name": "string",
      "lastName": "string",
      "last_name": "string",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show the getters also

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Note that even though the two classes look similar, the result for both is not. So there must be a difference between them, that you didn't post.

Comment: It seems `RequestDto` fields are using the default names, not the value from `@JsonProperty` either. Which is also problematic & weird

Comment: I am using Lombok for getters and setters

Comment: Could you show the rest controller?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Swagger?

Comment: @buræquete yes it is. I have tried various things like "@JsonProperty" on getter and then "@JsonUnwrapped". None of them is working for me

Comment: I think you have to try this `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)`. I think it gets fields from both fields and getters. The one above will only use fields. Put that above your Patient class.

Comment: I am using Swagger 2.4.0

Comment: Maybe your jackson version is old? I found [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2578), kinda similar, ignoring `@JsonProperty`. Though in your case it is both ignored & used weird really... Are you sure there are no differences between `Patient` & `RequestDto` classes?

Comment: please share the jackson dependencies along with version

Comment: You first need to diagnose what the actual problem is. Is it a problem with Jackson? Or with your code? Or with Swagger? A complete minimal example serializing an instance of your class with Jackson would allow telling that.

Comment: Got it. Have some issues with Swagger. "@jsonproperty" changes are working fine with other tools. I guess I need to update the Swagger.

Comment: Post all code please.

Comment: you can also post setter and getter methods. those play some important role while unmarshalling

Comment: Got the issue. Its with swagger version. I was using 2.4. After upgrading to 2.9 issue got resolved.